# VB.NET How to do changes to rows selected using LINQ?

Tags: vb.net, linq, datatable

I have the following code which selects some rows using LINQ depending on some conditions.

```
    Dim cname
    Dim Category
    Dim cprice

    Try
        For i = 0 To mainDatatable.Rows.Count - 1
            cname = mainDatatable.Rows(i)("cname")
            Category = mainDatatable.Rows(i)("ccategory")
            cprice = mainDatatable.Rows(i)("cprice")
            Dim nameparts() As String = cname.Split(New String() {" "}, StringSplitOptions.None)
            Dim query = From products In mainDatatable.AsEnumerable()
                        Where products.Field(Of Integer)("ccategory") = Category And products.Field(Of Double)("cprice") = cprice And products.Field(Of String)("cname").Contains(nameparts(0)) And products.Field(Of String)("cname").Contains(nameparts(1))
                        Select products
            If query.Count > 1 Then
                'then i want to do some changes to those rows
            End If
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

The code is working perfectly but I need to do changes on the selected rows. I'm not sure how to do it, for example i have a column called gprice and I want it to set it to some value for all the selected rows and save changes to `mainDatatable` ,would aprreciate your help.

To make it clear, suppose the row count in the `query`  is 6 then I want to make all the values for some column in the `query` = 1 and then update the values of the selected rows in the `mainDatatable`

------update

If you don't get it forget the above code and here is what I am trying to do

-Ii have a datatable it only have 2 columns product name and product price, now there are products with same name but different colors

-I want to group those products by pharsing the string name and check for other products with identical words in the name, only one word is allowed to differ which is the color,

-Also the price have to be the same between the products in that group and this is what the above LINQ code does and it does it perfectly

-My problem is i have added a third column called groupnumber, I want to add 1 for each product in the 1st group, 2 for each product in group 2nd and so on.

Comment: Do you even understand what the code is doing? Every single line in it? If not... I _strongly_ suggest you figure that out first, then you should be able to figure out how to make your changes.

Comment: i wrote this code..but how can i access the rows in the query without adding them to a datatable?

Comment: Just iterate over the query? Sorry, I still don't quite understand what you're asking. I understand that you want to write some values, so you'd use the `SetField()` method. But beyond that, I don't know what you're asking.

Comment: It seems that you're struggling with a problem and didn't even begin to find the best approach. You iterate through `mainDatatable` and within an iteration you iterate through a part of it again. That doesn't make sense. What you try to achieve should be done by grouping. Maybe you should step back and tell in words what you're trying to do and show sample input and output.

Comment: well it makes sense because i have to put the products in groups , what defines that a product belongs to a group is that it has same name different color same price and this is working perfectly i can see the results when i add them to a datatable and its just as i want it, what i am strugglin with is after i find that group of products how can i change the values of some coulumn and make all = 1 for the second group = 2 and so on, basicly my problem is i don't know how to access rows in query

Comment: also i've updated the question with what i am trying to do